# javascript is not giving the computer name

Tags: javascript, computer-name

I am Trying to Get the Client Computer name using javascript like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function GetComputerName() {
            try {
                var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
                alert(network.computerName);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert('a');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

But this is not returning any thing else exception.Plz Help me to find out the client computer name in Javascript.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: u need it for cross browser?

Comment: A crossbrowser solution would be to have a signed applet return the hostname.

Comment: What exactly is the exception? This should work fine (for IE only ofcourse), if you've correctly set Security options. Try to alert `e.Message` instead of `'a'` in `catch` block, or just remove `try..catch`.

Comment: I am Using Chrome and I Must Want to show in chrome